# Can I both declare a broad type and use inferred type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inferred-type

I frequently find that I want to declare that a constant object is of some broad type, so that the compiler can check the initialization.  But then when I *use* that object, I want to use the specific, *inferred* type.  I can find no way to access the inferred type of an object if I declare a type for it.  Example:

A spreadsheet consists of strings pointing at collections of CSS properties.  When initializing the spreadsheet, I want to enforce that the members of each style are CSS properties.  So:

```
type MyStyleDeclaration<K extends string = string> = { [key in K]: CSSProperties }

const myStyleSheet:MyStyleDeclaration {
    aStyle: { margin: 4 }
}
```

This enforces that my CSS property `margin` exists, but if I later foolishly try to access

`myStyleSheet.notAStyle`

the compiler doesn't know anything's wrong - the key could be any string.

On the other hand, if I don't declare the type of `myStyleSheet`, the compiler will correctly detect a bad reference like `myStyleSheet.notAStyle`.  And if I pass myStyleSheet to a generic function, declared as a `MyStyleDeclaration<K>`, `K` will be correctly inferred to be only the keys in the object.

BUT of course now the compiler won't detect anything wrong with:

```
const myStyleSheet {
    aStyle: { notAProperty: 4 }
}
```

Is there some way to have my cake and eat it, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way to have my cake and eat it, too?

The best I can come up with is this contraption:

```
class Checker<DeclaredType> {
    check<InferredType extends DeclaredType>(t: InferredType): InferredType {
        return t;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
type CSSProperties = { margin: number };

type MyStyleDeclaration<K extends string = string> = {[key in K]: CSSProperties }

const myStyleSheet1 = new Checker<MyStyleDeclaration>().check({
    aStyle: { notAProperty: 4 }
});

// Argument of type '{ aStyle: { notAProperty: number; }; }' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type 'MyStyleDeclaration<string>'.
//   Property 'aStyle' is incompatible with index signature.
//     Type '{ notAProperty: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
//       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'notAProperty' 
//       does not exist in type 'CSSProperties'.

    let p1 = myStyleSheet1.notAStyle;
// no error, but myStyleSheet1 has already failed type checking, so anyway...

const myStyleSheet2 = new Checker<MyStyleDeclaration>().check({
    aStyle: { margin: 4 }
});
// ok

let p2 = myStyleSheet2.notAStyle;
// Property 'notAStyle' does not exist on type '{ aStyle: { margin: number; }; }'.
```

I don't like this at all.

First, it adds unused object creation and method call for every check, but I don't think that runtime overhead is avoidable. After all, you want to have checks that are not built-in into the language.

Second, it's verbose - you can't get away with just one function call to do a custom check.  Unfortunately Typescript does not allow to use a generic function with two generic parameters when one parameter is inferred from the actual parameter and the other one explicit. So you have to have a class with one generic parameter, and non-static method with another one (because static class methods are not allowed to access generic class parameters), which leads to verbose syntax `new Checker<SomeType>().check({...})`. Looks too much like Java.

---

update

Indeed as Ed Staub suggested it could be simplified:

```
type CSSProperties = { margin: number };

type MyStyleDeclaration<K extends string = string> = {[key in K]: CSSProperties }

function checker<DeclaredType>() {
  return function<InferredType extends DeclaredType>(t: InferredType):InferredType{
      return t;
  }
}

const styleChecker = checker<MyStyleDeclaration>();

const myStyleSheet1 = styleChecker({
    aStyle: { notAProperty: 4 }
});
```

Comment: Nice approach!  I think maybe a higher-order function that returns the "check" function, rather than a class, may address some of the shortcomings.  I'll leave it for you for a day, in case you're interested in chasing it.